# Error Changing the XML Element of a overwritten property of a child class

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I am using the XmlSerializer.Deserialize() method in the System.Xml.Serialization dll in C#. I have a class that has a property that I would like to inherit but one of the properties in the parent class has a slightly different element name. Is there a graceful way to fix this.

```
public class Parent {
  public int ParentName { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent {
  [XmlElement("ChildName")]
  public new int ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting about 8 exceptions, but here is the error that is the most telling.

> InvalidOperationException: Member 'Child.ParentName' hides inherited member 'Parent.ParentName', but has different custom attributes.

Meaning my issue is with the [XmlElement("ChildName")] section. Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Comment: The best way of debugging to see actual issue is to create classes with data and then serialize.  Then compare the serialize xml against original xml file.

Comment: I already have data and working xml serialization methods. I only added this dummy class to explain my issue without extra sugar that was irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: If it is working then why are you posting?  Is the serialize data matching the xml you are trying to deserialize?